# QGIS LYON desktop cannot be opened on windows 7

Tags: qgis, windows-7, osgeo4w

I have installed QGIS lyon from

http://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.12.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

on win7.

I did not install the default data set.

On my desktop, there are some icons of QGIS.

When I clicked "QGIS Desktop 2.12.3" icon, I got a window telling me that it is setting up GUI and checking provider plugins.

But, after that, it disappeared. Nothing opened on my desktop.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: There was some kind of error during the installation. Look into `C:\Program Files\QGIS Lyon\postinstall.log` for details. Did earlier versions of QGIS work for you?

Comment: Try reinstall QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.12.3-1-Setup-x86_64.exe with right mouse button on it and run as Administrator.